# Light reading diode?

Tags: photodiode, light, light-sensor

I’m trying to think of a device to measure amount of UVA & UVB daylight for plants in my shed and so trying to work out what I could use to measure:

1. The amount of light
2. Its type
3. Its time
4. Be able to either not react to artificial lighting or know the difference to assist the calculator.

So far my searches have directed me towards a photodiode of types, and that’s what I have.   I am not an engineer, I am quite keen to learn of and delve into topics and info.

If anyone can SHED some LIGHT (praying my humour helps here) that would be awesome.

Comment: The answer to this question looks appropriate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/192224/photodiode-amplifier-circuit

Comment: Do you really need UVA and UVB to be measured separately? Are you looking for an analog or microcontroller solution? (are you motivated to learn microcontrollers). Besides the VEML6075 breakout board recommended by Michel Keijzers, you will also need a microcontroller (Arduino or similar) and LCD display. A big project if you have no experience in any of this.

Comment: how they did it in the olden days was a diffraction grating (which sends different wavelengths in different directions) followed by a line of thermometers (get hot when light hits them)

Comment: Are you ok knowing relative levels of UVB to UVA or do you need absolute? Calibration will be complex if you want absolute numbers, but relative is not too hard.

Answer (score 6):

Why not using a dedicated UVA/UVB sensor for that, like the
[VEML6075 breakout board](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-veml6075-uva-uvb-uv-index-sensor/arduino-test) or the [VEML6075 basic IC](https://content.arduino.cc/assets/Iot-Prime/VEML6075.pdf)?